# How to kill the old process of crontab script in linux

Tags: linux, cron

I have a Korn shell script which runs in cronjob. This Korn shell script has to kill a process which is running and start the new process again.

```
#!/bin/ksh
#
 # Startup script 

case "$1" in
start)
echo -n "Starting interpreward services: "
cd /home/to/folder
/home/user/folder/jdk1.8.0_121/bin/java -Xmx512m -Xms256m -jar file.jar file=file.properties

;;
stop)
echo -n "Stopping interpTestreward services: "
pkill subTest
 ;;
status)
status interpTest
;;
restart|reload)
$0 stop
$0 start
;;
condrestart)
$0 status
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
$0 stop
$0 start
fi
;;
*)
 echo "Usage: interpreward {start|stop|status|restart}"
exit 1
esac
exit 0
```

is there something to mention in the code of the script to kill the old process ?

Comment: You could just write a pidfile when the process starts, and use that to (semi-) identify the process to be killed.  You might want to do some sanity checking that it is indeed the correct process (e.g. check its executable, root directory, etc) before killing.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but i'm not a linux expert , I found this line on internet :kill -9 $(ps | grep "server1" | grep -v grep | awk '{ print $1 }'), can do the work if I add it to the script

Comment: Ah, cargo cult programming; what could possibly go wrong?  ;-)

Comment: `pkill` is probably defined in another file that you need to include.